# check for image in local , if exits show in app ,if not take url from websql database and download and show in app

Tags: image, cordova, local-storage

i am new in cordova android development.(HTMl5 css3 js)

i am making android app **employee info** .
in which if i can search by first name .
it will get all the text data(ie. emp_id ,first name ,last name ,branch, designation ,contact no. reportees ) from websql.
i want to store image URl in websql. then when i search by name it will check image in local if exist display it , if not get url from websql by employee id , download in background and show in app.

is it possible ?
whats should i do?
plz give me proper guidance to make these project from scratch.

If anyone have any pointer will be really helpful.

Thanks. :)

Comment: if url image is not load by some error like no internet connection , it will display default image like image placeholder

Comment: Are you saying you will have a column in your WebSQL db for image, and the value represents a file on the file system? Or is the URL of the image remote?

Comment: image url column is storing images from internet/database.

Comment: I really don't understand your issue then. If your WebSQL table has a column that has an image url, then you can select it, and render that in the dom. Right?